# What is b:if? How do I make it return true if it's home page?

Tags: xml, blogger

I came across the b:if argument in Blogger, I'm not to sure how to use it. 
I need to make a condition return true if it's the front page. How do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<b:if>` is a so called widget tag. See the [complete list of widget tags](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=de&answer=46995) in the Blogger help pages. For the values of the condition you can use [layout data tags](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47270).

For the detection for the front page, there are at least two possibilities:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageName == ""'>
  <!-- Place markup for the front page and archives here -->
<b:else/>
  <!-- Place markup for posts here -->
</b:if>
```

Alternative:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
  <!-- Place markup for the posts here -->
<b:else/>
  <!-- Place markup for front page and archive here -->
</b:if>
```

Have look at an [example to customize the page title](http://websitetemplatedatabase.com/blogging/30-blogger-page-name-page-title) for search engine optimization.